# Scrape older versions of playstore apps

Tags: web-scraping, version, store, playback

I want to scrape data of all the google play store apps historically.
Basically I want all the details changed in an app over a period of time.
Is there a way to do it.

Comment: If you're using Python, have a look at already implemented packages on PyPI that focuses on [extracting data from Google Play](https://pypi.org/search/?q=google+play). I'm not sure if some of them are working but have a try.

Comment: You only get the available meta data using scrapper, i need the meta data for previous versions as well